# SELECT não retorna nada quando coloco uma clausula WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Quando eu executo o seguinte comando sql eu recebo um retorno vazio, mesmo eu indicando um id que está  presente em algumas linhas da tabela a ser pesquisada

```
SELECT e.data_request,
       e.id_exchange,
       e.data_exchange,
       e.data_refound,
       s.description AS status,
       e.id_status,
       t.description AS type,
       u1.name AS requester,
       u2.name AS substitute,
       u3.name AS coord 
FROM exchanges AS e 
INNER JOIN status AS s ON e.id_status = s.id_status 
INNER JOIN users AS u1 ON e.requester = u1.id_user 
INNER JOIN users AS u2 ON e.substitute = u2.id_user 
INNER JOIN users AS u3 ON e.id_coord = u3.id_user 
INNER JOIN types AS t ON e.id_type = t.id_types 
WHERE e.id_coord = 1
OR e.id_rh = 1
```

---

No banco de dados os seguintes dados estão cadastrados:

Tabela users:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Tabela exchanges:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

e esse é o retorno que recebo ao executar o SQL:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Consegui resolver com o auxilio de um amigo de trabalho, o erro estava em um item cadastrado que era um FK, porem o registro de usuário com a fk em questão tinha sido deletado. A solução era simplesmente colocar um constraint de FK para o campo id_coord